# Awesomium WebView.HTML остается пустым после указания Source

Tags: c#, awesomium

С WebControl было то же самое, пока я не вставил его на форму. Я так понимаю, что он отключен, пока не находится на форме.
Как все-таки заставить перейти WebView по ссылке, не добавляя его на форму?

Answer (score 0):

Делаю так, все работает:

```
var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080);
webView.Source = new Uri("http://google.com");
while (webView.IsLoading)
{
    WebCore.Update();
}
Console.WriteLine(webView.HTML);
```